# How to connect with DISTO D510 with BLE on Windows 10?

Tags: c#, bluetooth-lowenergy, windows-10-universal

I'm trying to receive data from the DISTO D510 equipped with BLE.

Actually I can pair with it, and receive its advertisement packets with `BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher` but I'm not able to get the measures since I don't know where to look for them.

I tried to scan every service and characteristics found within the advertisement event args but I don't see any changes on the raw data when I take a measure with the device.

Does anybody know how to do it?

Comment: Do you have the instruction manual? Is this an advertised feature, or are you trying to interject a datastream meant for another purpose? Does the D-510 have 4.0 smart BT?

Comment: Why not just use one of the built-in transfer apps? https://lasers.leica-geosystems.com/disto/leica-disto-apps

Comment: If possible I prefere to not use the disto transfer pc app because it inputs the data like the keyboard so I need to ask the user to set the focus to an input field or manage in some magic manner the focus between the various input fields of the application...

With the previous disto version I could manage very easily the bt connection with the 32feet library...

Comment: and yes it has the 4.0 smart BT